# Intercept swipe on different near TextView

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

i have three textviews, tv_one and tv_two, tv_three and i would intercept swipe event when user swipe from a textview to another.

I've write this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        // do something
        return true;
    }

    }
    return false;
}
```

In this way i can intercept when user press first textview and when release his finger from the screen. i would know how can i do for intercept swipe between that views.
For example, if user swipe from tv_one to tv_three, app should know that path was from one to three. how can i do?

Comment: I think you should make your onTouch event on a layout contains the three textViews and compute git event.getX and event.getY where the touch at every point and then you can tell if the swipe started at one textView and went to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use View coordinates for define down/up position.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = currentX;
            startY = currentY;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveX = currentX;
            moveY = currentY;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = currentX;
            upY = currentY;
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And check:

```
int top = tv_one.getTop();
int left = tv_one.getLeft();
int width = tv_one.getWidth();
int height = tv_one. getHeight();

RectF tv_one_rect = new RectF(left, top, left + width, top + height);
boolean insideTv_one = tv_one_rect.contains(moveX, moveY);
```